# Reading the same record from sqlite db in iphone app

Tags: ios5, sqlite, xcode4.2

In my iphone app I use a sqlite db. I have an icon that starts the reading from db and stores it in table view. The problem is: if I select the icon again, it doubles the table view with the same record. I know the reason, because every time I select the icon the program goes to 'readSalesFromDatabase' and to 'tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath'. The problem is how to avoid this?
Here is my code:

### In AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// db name
databaseName = @"saSh5.sqlite";    
//creating db
[self checkAndCreateDatabase];
//deals will hold the retrive data
deals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
return YES;
```

}

```
-(void) readSalesFromDatabase {

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    // const char *sqlStatement = "select * from UsersSale";
    const char *sqlStatement = "select us.userID , us.saleStoreID,  from UsersSale us  order by us.saleID";        


    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
         while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // Read the data from the result row
            NSInteger auserID = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0); 
            NSInteger asalStoreID = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 1); 

            // Create a new  Sale object with the data from the database                
            Deals *sfl  = [[Deals alloc] initWithName:auserID 
                                                            saleStoreID:asalStoreID]; 

            [deals addObject:sfl];
            [sfl release];

        }
}
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

}

### In Controller:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  self.title = @"Deals";
  self.myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds  style:UITableViewStylePlain];
  self.myTableView.dataSource = self; 
  self.myTableView.delegate = self;
  [self.view addSubview:self.myTableView]; 

  AppDelegate *appDelegate = ( AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  [appDelegate readSalesFromDatabase];
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UILabel *product, *name; 
UITableViewCell *result = nil;
if ([tableView isEqual:self.myTableView]){
    static NSString *TableViewCellIdentifier = @"MyCells";
    result = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier];
    if (result == nil){
        result = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                  initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier];

    result = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                   reuseIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier] autorelease];
     AppDelegate *appDelegate = ( AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Deals *dls = (Deals *)[appDelegate.deals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
    result.textLabel.lineBreakMode= UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    product = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25.0, 0.0, 220.0, 15.0)] autorelease];
    product.tag = MAINLABEL_TAG;
    product.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    product.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    product.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    product.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    product.text = dls.saleSpecificProduct;        

    [result.contentView addSubview:product];

}   

return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that whenever you select the icon the `readSalesFromDatabase` method gets called, which appends the data in '`deals`' array each time. So avoid the redundancy of the same data, make sure to remove all objects from deals array before calling `readSalesFromDatabase`  to proceed further i.e.
     [`deals` `removeallobjects`];
Hope this will work.